# Cassandra sets or composite columns

Tags: cassandra

I am storing account information in Cassandra.  Each account has lists of data associated with it.  For example, an account may have a list of friends and a list of liked books.  Queries on accounts will always want all friends or all liked books or all of both.  No filtering or searching is needed on either.  The list of friends and books can grow and shrink.

Is it better to use a set column type or composite columns for this scenario?

Comment: If the usage model changes to where the friend collection and the likes collection are not always wanted together with the account, is it better to break the friends and likes into their own separate column family?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you not to use sets if

1. You are concerned about disk space(as each value is allocated a cell in disk + data space for metadata of each cell which is 15 bytes if am not wrong. Now that consumes a lot if your data is a growing one).
2. Not going to grow a lot of data in that particular row as each time ,the cells are to be fetched from different sstable .

In these kind of cases, the more preferred option would be a json array. You shall store it as a text and back the data from that.

Set (or any other collections ) use case was brought in for a completely different perspective. If you are having a particular value inside the list or a value has to be updated frequently inside the same collection, you shall make use of the collections .

My take on your query will be this.

Store all account specific info in a json object of friends that has a value as list of books .

Comment: Is there an advantage to json over another serialization format like Protocol Buffers?

Comment: Yes...serialisation overhead is very high for wide rows. A serialized column requires deserialisation each time too in retrieval.

Answer (score 1):

Sets are good for smaller collections of data, if you expect your friends / liked books lists to grow constantly and get large (there isn't a golden number here) it would be better to go with composite columns as that model scales out better than collections and allows for straight up querying compared to requiring secondary indexes on collections.

Comment: How would I create the composite columns?  If I add both, the "friends" and "likes", in the primary key list, I cannot insert friends or likes independently.  ie.  INSERT with a new friend but without a new like will fail for a missing mandatory key.

Comment: Your use case cannot use composite key unless you have a default for any value. Composite columns are good if you are having search filters. As you have stated that you are not going to use search filters,json will be best suited.